# Companion ads for preroll for Brightcove videos

Tags: google-dfp, brightcove

I have a companion ad of 300X250 scheduled to be playing with a certain preroll ad through dfp. When the brightcove video is played, the preroll starts and it should be displaying the companion ad in the neighboring div as well but it isn't doing so currently.

I have tried using the gpt calls for companion cube ads as detailed here https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/companions/companions-gpt as well as using the brightcove 'bcsyncroadblock' callback function  as detailed here http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/working-vast-20-external-companion-ads but haven't been able to get the companion ads to load.

Would appreciate inputs from anyone who has encountered/resolved a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

The IMA libraries do handle all the companion interactions. If you're using IMA3 as the ad source for an ad-enabled Video Cloud player, the first link you used would be the best resource. I was able to get this working by following that procedure:

https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/companions/companions-gpt

In the Advertising Module of Video Cloud, I set the ad server URL and chose DFP IMA3 as the ad source.

Next, I copied the Javascript publishing code for the player and video from the Media Module's Quick Publish feature.

I then pasted that player code into the  of the page code from Example 2, above the  for the companions.

To rule out an issue with ad trafficking, I would start out with DFP's Sample ad tag as I did. A sample is available from the DFP VAST inspector:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/vastinspector_dual

Currently the sample ad tag provided is below, you can add this as your test player's Ad Server URL in Video Cloud Studio:
http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=400x300&iu=%2F6062%2Fiab_vast_samples&ciu_szs=300x250%2C728x90&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=[referrer_url]&correlator=[timestamp]&cust_params=iab_vast_samples%3Dlinear

If the above test works but your ads aren't, you may need to review what size ad slots you are using and need, and get a bit more into the Google code.

The VAST companions roadblock feature is not active in the case of IMA ad source, so those instructions won't work.